# java error:constructor High in class High cannot be applied to given types. why this error comes?

Tags: java

```
class High
{
    public High(String s)
    {
        System.out.print("From High");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main extends High
{
    public Main(String s)
    {
        System.out.print("From Low");
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Main m=new Main("HighLow");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do with your code, but the problem is that in your `Main` constructor you are not explicitly calling the `High` constructor (since you are extending it you must). When you ommit the explicit call, the compiler will add it for you, but using the no-argument constructor, which does not exist in `High`. The consequence is that you must add the call on your own as follows:

```java
public class Main extends High {
    public Main(String s) {
        super(s);  // This is the line you are missing
        System.out.print("From Low");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main("HighLow");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```